# How to Remove Ubuntu 10.04/10.10/etc without Replacing It with Another OS?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, uninstall

Is there a way to completely remove Ubuntu 10.04/10.10/etc from a HDD without replacing it with another OS, so the HDD will return to its origin-state (empty)? I have googling this, as well as using the search facility in this site, but still came empty-handed.

Most of the solution for removing/deleting Ubuntu presume that we will install Windows 7/Vista/XP in the HDD and suggesting to use Windows bootable disk/USB to format the Ubuntu partition then install the Windows. But what I am intend to do is to get an empty/clean HDD without any system within. I also don't have any Windows bootable disk/USB.

Can anyone shed some light about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are several ways to completely wipe a hard disk. But, what you can do is download the GParted Live CD/USB from [**here**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.16.1-1/gparted-live-0.16.1-1-i486.iso). Burn it to a disc or make a bootable USB, then boot it up. In GParted, simply right click and delete all the partitions in the hard disk, and apply. If you can't right click and delete, first try to right click and unmount, and then delete. Just make sure you're performing these operations on your hard disk and not on another external HDD or USB stick. To be on the safe side, remove any other peripheral disks.

Comment: Thanks. I will take your advice and use GParted. I am planning to download the 12.04 iso so I can utilize it as bootable USB to delete the Ubuntu partition. I will come back here if this option doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can always delete/format/shred your partition or whole partition table using `Ubuntu` bootable usb/disk.

You can do so easily by using gparted which is installed by default in live ubuntu.[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but I do not think gparted actually writes zeros or deletes the data. Typically files can be recovered using testdisk or other forensics.

Comment: Yes you are right @bodhi.zazen. It's a pleasure to see you around :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think the best method is to write all zeros to the drive using dd.

Boot the live CD and

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

Change `/dev/sda` to your hard drive.

The advantage of dd is that it overwrites your data as well as the MBR.

Your other option would be scrub

```
scrub -p dod /dev/sda
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/scrub

scrub is faster and the -p dod option is compliant with dod standards.

Either method will leave you with a "clean" hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @bodhi.zazen. The 'dd' command should be execute in Terminal right? So what am I to do is boot the live USB, open the Terminal, and enter the 'dd' line? Apologise for this silly question, I am totally new not only to Ubuntu but also to all-computer-things. Actually I have downloaded 12.04 iso and burned it to a live USB to utilize the GParted. But I would prefer the 'dd' if it can assure a clean HDD.

Comment: yes, run dd in a terminal

Comment: If I execute the command, is it possible to utilize the HDD again in the future? It wouldn't broken isn't it? Just in case I want to add the HDD again in my PC.

Comment: if you use dd you can use the hd , you will need to partition and format it, just as if it were new.